# Xcode Show only valid code signing identites in Build Settings

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Does anybody know if its possible to get Xcode to only show valid code signing identities when you go to Build Settings > Code Signing > Code Signing Identity?

Currently it shows all code signing identities and greys out the non-valid ones, but the problem is I have hundreds and the list is getting bigger and bigger so it makes for a lot of scrolling to find the proper one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that through settings in xcode. It has to be done manually by removing the invalid identities. Here is the link to apple doc's that clearly mentions that. Take a look at the section " keep your profile library clean".

[Apple documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html)

Comment: I know how to remove unwanted profiles but this has nothing to do with keeping profile library clean... these are all active profiles. However if what I want cannot be done then I will mark this correct.

Comment: It is the same with active ones. No way to set a filter or prevent them from showing up. I know it sucks, but that's how xcode is for now.